# How can I stop a colliding object from continuing falling after several seconds (AS3)?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe, flash-cc

I have a problem that is related to AS3, it involves two code locations (MainTimeline and an MC-extending class), as well as a basic physics engine function. The problem is that when the objects collide (`enemy` and `ground`), they stay collided, but after a short period of time (2-6 seconds), the object that is gravitated teleports under the object it collided with, and continues to fall.
Thank you for any assistance.
P.S. I do not prefer document class solutions.

Timeline code:
`

```
        stop();

        var ground: MovieClip;

        var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy();

        stage.addChild(enemy);

        enemy.x = 400;

        enemy.y = 150;

        enemy.rotation = 0;

        enemy.addEventListener("enterFrame", collisions);

        function collisions(e: Event): void {

        var collision: Boolean = false;

        if (ground.hitTestObject(enemy)) {
            collision = true;
        }

        if (collision) {
            while (collision) {
                enemy.y -= 0.1;
                collision = false;
            if (ground.hitTestObject(enemy)) {
                collision = true;

            }
            }
            Class(Enemy).yVel = 0;
        }
}
```

Class code:

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
public class Enemy extends MovieClip {
        
        var xVel: int;
        var yVel: int;
        
    public function Enemy() {
        // constructor code
        addEventListener("enterFrame", onEnterFrame);
        
    }
    
    function onEnterFrame(e: Event): void {
        
        yVel += 2;
        this.x = xVel;
        this.y = yVel;
    }
    
    
}
```

}

Comment: This **Class(Enemy).yVel = 0;** is obviously wrong and it does nothing meaningful (should actually produce an error, I wonder, why not). If you meant to halt the fall, you need to alter the member of the enemy instance (the one that is falling), like **enemy.yVel = 0;**

Comment: @Organis whenever I use your answer, the `enemy` respawns at the starting point it spawned at. The `enemy` is a child object, whereas `ground` is a library symbol MC.

Comment: Ah. Indeed. I assumed **yVel** to be a *velocity* variable, but now looking closer at your code I see you don't treat it that way. Makes sense.

Comment: @Organis so what might you suggest to fix either problems?

Comment: At the moment you have that **yVel** property that constantly increase, so the **enemy** never actually stops falling, but as long as it collides with the **ground** you can't see it. Then it grows enough to *fall through* and you can see it again. I think, you have two options here: 1) Level up your understanding of physics and figure why **this.y = yVel;** is not what *velocity* is supposed to be, or 2) Use a dedicated 2D-physics framework (like **Box2D**) that solves all the physics routine for you.

Comment: @Organis I tried `this.x += yVel;`, but this doesn't work

Comment: Of course it doesn't. You pour the **Y**-velocity into **X**-coordinate.

Comment: @AlexSmart Is the enemy supposed to stop when `collisions = true;`? If yes, then why not  also do a `enemy.removeEventListener("enterFrame", collisions);`  at same point?. It might help to also remove the event in **Enemy** Class otherwise your **yVel** is  increased by +2 every frame (_eg:_ at 30 FPS) regardless of collision or not. Once collision happens, **Enemy** doesn't need to keep increasing it's own **yVel**. The event should stop. Maybe have two public functions `moveEnemy` and `stopEnemy` where the functions respectively add or remove the Enterframe event. _Eg:_ `enemy.stopEnemy();`

Comment: @Organis Nvm. Problem solved.